# Regular expression replace

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Reg Ex script

- remove all symbols
- allow max 1 hyphen connected to each other
- allow max 1 period total

example:

- Mike&Ike  **output is: MikeIke**
- Mike-Ike  **output is: Mike-Ike**
- Mike-Ike-Jill  **output is: Mike-Ike-Jill**
- Mike--Ike-Jill  **output is: Mike-Ike-Jill**
- Mike--Ike---Jill  **output is: Mike-Ike-Jill**
- Mike.Ike.Bill  **output is: Mike.IkeBill**
- Mike***Joe **output is: MikeJoe**
- Mike123 **output is: Mike123**

Comment: Can you put some effort into fixing your question?  Your requirements are oddly fragmented.  I think I can guess what you mean but you should be the one fixing it.  You can use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5463310/edit) below the question.

Comment: What is the rule that gives 'Mike.lkeBill' in the sixth example?

Comment: 'allow max 1 period total' probably needs some kind of lookbehind or lookahead which is not supported by all regex flavors. Please specify the language you're using.

Comment: You'll need 3 regex substitutions to achieve what you want. The above commenter noted, the "period" requirement cannot be achieved in all regex flavors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something with several passes.
it's kind of generic workaround that could be shorted by using lookbehind.
(not all regex flavors do support this)

1. remove multiple `-` with regex `-{2,}`
2. remove symbols except `-.` with regex `[^-\.A-Za-z0-9]`
3. replace first `.` with a temp character e.g. `!` and replace remaining `.`
4. replace the `!` from last step with `.`

***update*** using C# .net
(I'm not a C# programmer, used this [regex tester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php) and this [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx) for C# .net regex flavor.)

```
String str = "Mike&Ike ......";
str = Regex.Replace( str, @"-+", @"-" );
str = Regex.Replace( str, @"(?<=\.)(.*?)\.", @"$1" );
str = Regex.Replace( str, @"[^\w\r\n]", @"" );
```

1. replacing multipe `-` with single `-`
2. remove `.` if it's not the first `.` using positiv lookbehind `(?<=...)`
3. remove symbols (actually everything not a word character or newline) `\w` is short for `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samples = (
    "Mike&Ike"          => "MikeIke",
    "Mike-Ike"          => "Mike-Ike",
    "Mike-Ike-Jill"     => "Mike-Ike-Jill",
    "Mike--Ike-Jill"    => "Mike-Ike-Jill",
    "Mike--Ike---Jill"  => "Mike-Ike-Jill",
    "Mike.Ike.Bill"     => "Mike.IkeBill",
    "Mike***Joe"        => "MikeJoe",
    "Mike123"           => "Mike123",
);

while (my($got, $want) = splice(@samples, 0, 2)) {
    my $had = $got;
    for ($got) {
  # 1) Allow max 1 dashy bit connected to each other.
        s/ ( \p{Dash} ) \p{Dash}+                           /$1/xg;
  # 2) Allow max 1 period, total.
        1 while s/ ^ [^.]* \. [^.]* \K \.                   //x   ;
  # 3) Remove all symbols...
        s/ (?! [\p{Dash}.] ) [\p{Symbol}\p{Punctuation}]    //xg  ;
  #                   ...and punctuation
  #       except for dashy bits and dots.
    }

    if ($got eq $want) { print "RIGHT" }
    else               { print "WRONG" }
    print ":\thad\t<$had>\n\twanted\t<$want>\n\tgot\t<$got>\n";
}
```

Generates:

```
RIGHT:  had <Mike&Ike>
    wanted  <MikeIke>
    got <MikeIke>
RIGHT:  had <Mike-Ike>
    wanted  <Mike-Ike>
    got <Mike-Ike>
RIGHT:  had <Mike-Ike-Jill>
    wanted  <Mike-Ike-Jill>
    got <Mike-Ike-Jill>
RIGHT:  had <Mike--Ike-Jill>
    wanted  <Mike-Ike-Jill>
    got <Mike-Ike-Jill>
RIGHT:  had <Mike--Ike---Jill>
    wanted  <Mike-Ike-Jill>
    got <Mike-Ike-Jill>
RIGHT:  had <Mike.Ike.Bill>
    wanted  <Mike.IkeBill>
    got <Mike.IkeBill>
RIGHT:  had <Mike***Joe>
    wanted  <MikeJoe>
    got <MikeJoe>
RIGHT:  had <Mike123>
    wanted  <Mike123>
    got <Mike123>
```

Comment: Hey Tom, what's that `\K`? (Can't find it described in MRE3)

Comment: @ridgerunner: `\K` is a way to **“keep”** everything that’s been matched so far.  It’s a shortcut for an extra capture group and dummy-replacement.

Comment: @Tom: Cool thanks. Looks like I'm going to have to sit down and learn Perl after all - (Lots of regex goodness in there...) Is there a _really good_ book you could recommend? (I've got your Camel book 3rd edition but its more than 10 years old) I'm getting older and can only fit so many languages into my (fading) brain! Thanks again.

Comment: @ridgeway: There’ve been a lot of regex enhancements in each major (even-numbered) release of Perl, with the most of them coming in 5.10.  I don’t know of any book that yet documents all those.  I’m trying, but it’s a biggish job. If you look around at my SO postings in the regex category over the last 6 months here, you can find quite a bit of that. Grammatical regexes, Unicode wonders, named groups, etc.